# What is the difference in getting an enum back or getting an enumerator back?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference in getting an enum back or getting an enumerator back?

Is an enum an object and an enumerator an object that does stum to an enum?

Comment: can you illustrate the question with some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "getting an enum back" are you referring to the `to_enum` method of some classes? In this case "enum" is just short for "enumerable," i.e. `to_enum` returns an object of class [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html). Ruby's standard library has no other concept called "enum."